# how prevent include 2 times but if not included before include now

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have 1 file named header-guest.php
when you are open this link http://royta.ir/badurl
this code will run:

```
if(!isset($headerload)){
if(isset($_COOKIE['userid'])){
    include_once('tmp/header.php');
}
else{
    include_once('tmp/header-guest.php');
}
}
```

and when you click on بازگشت به خانه
with ajax this code will run in #content

```
if(!isset($headerload)){
if(isset($_COOKIE['userid'])){
    include_once('tmp/header.php');
}
else{
    include_once('tmp/header-guest.php');
    include_once('block/index-visitor.php');
}
}
```

and in header-guest.php we have this code

```
<? echo $sitetitle; $headerload = 1;?>
```

but when you click on badurl and then click on بازگشت به خانه
header-guest.php will run 2 times
how i prevent it?

Comment: include_once('tmp.header.php');

Comment: Do you mean that it will run once when you load the URL and once when you run the Ajax? If you don't want that, simply remove the include statements from the Ajax-serving code

Comment: (If you want the script to be able to serve both Ajax and regular requests, use a query string when sending the Ajax request and decide whether to show the headers based on that)

Comment: thats nice idea but there is no solve for my current code?

Comment: You'll have to explain why that option isn't workable for you. Otherwise we'll just be taking random guess after random guess until one of them happens to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it
i add this code in my js for ajax load

```
$.ajax({
            url: location,
            data: {headerload:555},
            success: function(result) {
```

so i add this in my pages

```
if(!isset($headerload) and !isset($_GET['headerload'])){
```

so its will not load two times now

Answer (score 3):

to prevent loading resources twice use `require_once` or `include_once` . it will prevent the resource from being loaded twice if you happen to put two `include_once` statements for the same resource.

Comment: i test it but its include 2 times again plz see [link]http://royta.ir/badurl and click on بازگشت به خانه

Comment: your missing one more spot where is it originally loaded?

Comment: when you open badurl page with this code if(!isset($headerload)){
 if(isset($_COOKIE['userid'])){
  include_once('tmp/header.php');
 }
 else{
  include_once('tmp/header-guest.php');
 }
}
?>

Comment: so thats where the duplicate header is coming from, where is the original header set

Comment: first you open this code in comment when open royta.ir/badurl and when click on بازگشت به خانه that code in my question will run ... how prevent load 2 time ?